# How do I get $resource to resolve its promise in test environment

Tags: angular-resource, httpbackend

I have a controller that needs to run several asynchronous methods that interact with the data on the client and make no calls to the server.  I have one method working fine in the browser, but I want to drive the methods with tests and I can't get it to work in the test environment (Karma and Mocha).  The reason is that the empty array that $resource.query() returns never gets populated in the test environment because the promise doesn't get resolved.  Here is my beforeEach in the test suite.

```
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, scheduleService){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    sc = $controller('scheduleCtrl', {
        $scope: scope, service: scheduleService
    });
    scope.$apply();
    }));
```

scheduleCtrl has a property schedule that is assigned to the result of Resource.query() in it's constructor.  I can see the three returned objects loaded into the MockHttpExpectation.

[image]

But when I go to run the test sc.schedule is an still an empty array, so the test fails.  How do I get the Resource.query() to resolve in the test?

Answer (score 0):

Resource.query() works with promisses, which is a assync process.

It happens that your test execute before the assynchronous request have completed and before array gets populated.

You could use $httpBackend so you can call expect after $httpBackend.flush().

Or you could retrieve the $promisse returned from Resource.query().$promisse on your test and do the expectation inside its implementation.

Ex:

```
$scope.promisse = Resource.query().$promisse;

sc.promisse(function(values) {
  expect(values.length).not.toBe(0);
});
```

Comment: I use $httpBackend.  It is working fine to get data to the browser.  In the test, if I use &httpBackend.flush() I get an error that there is nothing to flush.

Comment: When I enclose the expectation inside the then method of a promise, it always passes.  But a console.writeline inside the same method says that values (in your example) is undefined.